# Minima in the interior of a set.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a real continuous, and differentiable, function in a compact set where the function takes values $f(x)\le \alpha$, so, for Weierstrass I know that there are at least one minimum inside it. I have to prove that the set of minima is in the interior of this set. I wanted to construct another compact set inside it to prove that, is the right choice or there is a better one?

Thanks

Comment: The minimum of $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ is not attained at an interior point.

Comment: Is the set over which you are minimizing convex?